# How to display a Grid cell tooltip in Vaadin Flow

Tags: tooltip, vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin14

With Vaadin 8 you could set a tooltip for a Grid cell. This feature is not available in Vaadin Flow (currently using v 11.0.0). Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no built-in feature yet. The easiest way is probably to set "title" attribute of the element. One example is to use TemplateRenderer, and there is example of that here

https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/java-examples/using-templates

Copying the relevant part of the code from the example above

```
grid.addColumn(TemplateRenderer.<Person> of(
        "<div title='[[item.name]]'>[[item.name]]<br><small>[[item.yearsOld]]</small></div>")
        .withProperty("name", Person::getName).withProperty("yearsOld",
                person -> person.getAge() > 1
                        ? person.getAge() + " years old"
                        : person.getAge() + " year old"))
        .setHeader("Person");
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @Tatu-Lund's answer I got the idea, but since the link is not referring to a valid location anymore, and also the example code with `div` can bring other complexities into the game I decided to post another answer.

Using `div` as the wrapper element to have the `title` attribute would work, but it will prevent the columns to be resized. So using `span` would be a good replacement.

Also, setting the `title` would help with a normal tooltip to show up, but it is not enough for accessibility support. Setting the `aria-label` in addition to the `title` would make it smoother:

```
grid.addColumn(TemplateRenderer.<Person> of(
    "<span title='[[item.name]]' aria-label='[[item.name]]'>[[item.name]]</span>")
    .withProperty("name", Person::getName)
    .setHeader("Person");
```

However, this is not a complete workaround as this would not help to browse the web app on touch devices. Please refer to the following issue for more information: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/4169