# Vaadin 14 Grid add Tooltips

Tags: vaadin14

I am using Vaadin 14 and I want to add tooltips to the grid rows. Is there anything the framworks offers, that i did not find? I am not sure what to write any further. I have looked in the api docs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display a Grid cell tooltip in Vaadin Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52344881/how-to-display-a-grid-cell-tooltip-in-vaadin-flow)

Answer (score 0):

I did solve this by creating a ComponentCollum that has the tooltip attached.